# Trouble with JavaScript collection of document elements

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, getelementsbytagname

I'm not sure if I'm on the wrong course altogether, or just missing a minor bit. I have a page that has sections, subsections, and subsubsections. The latter are  elements that all share a common formatting:

```
<select id="SubSubFlood"  class='hidden'>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select id="SubSubHome"  class='hidden'>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

I can't name each one explicitly because they're dynamically generated, but they all start with "SubSub". I'm trying to create code that will change all of the SubSubs to class='hidden', then change the one I want to be visible to class='unhidden'.  Here is my attempt:

```
function ShowSubSub(SelectID) {
    var SubSub = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
    var item;
    for (item in SubSub) {
        if (item.ID.match(/SubSub.*/)) {            
            item.className = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    item = document.getElementById(SelectID);
    item.className = 'unhidden';
}
```

Where am I missing the boat? How do I get JavaScript to change every  tag with an ID that starts with "SubSub" to class="hidden"?

Comment: Can't use `for ... in` loop on an HTMLCollection. You'll need to use a traditional `for` loop. Alternatively, if you use `document.querySelectorAll('select')` you will get a NodeList and can then use `forEach`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `for...in` is for iterating over object properties, not for arrays - for those it is `for ... of` and that is safe on anything that is `iterable` (including `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection`).

Comment: `item.ID` I assume will always return  `undefined`. Maybe you meant `item.id`?

Answer (score 5):

`SubSub` will contain an [*array like* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), so when you put it in a `for each` loop, you'll be enumerating it's properties, not the elements themselves. So item in the loop will not be the first select, it'll be `0`. I suggest changing it to a normal `for` loop

```js
function ShowSubSub(SelectID) {
  var SubSub = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
  var item;
  for (var i =0; i < SubSub.length; i++) {
    if (SubSub[i].id.match(/SubSub.*/)) {
      SubSub[i].className = 'hidden';
    }
  }
  item = document.getElementById(SelectID);
  item.className = 'unhidden';
}

ShowSubSub('SubSubHome')
```

```css
.hidden{

display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="SubSubFlood" class='hidden'>
  <option>Flood</option>
</select>
<select id="SubSubHome" class='hidden'>
  <option>Home</option>
</select>
```

P.S. is there any reason for having an `unhidden` class, can't you just remove the `hidden` class?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Tested it out, and it did just what I needed it to.

Answer (score 2):

This replies to the question:

> How do I get JavaScript to change every tag with an ID that starts with "SubSub" to class="hidden"?

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]')].forEach(section => section.className.add('hidden'))
```

will achieve just that.

So let's break that up:

1. First of all use an attribute selector that matches all elements that have an `id` value starting with `SubSub`: `[id^="SubSub"]`.

   Query the document for all of these: `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]')`
2. Spread the `NodeList` you get to into an `array` using `...` (spread operator):

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]')]
   ```

   Alternatively, you could also use `Array.from(iterable)`:

   ```
   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]'))
   ```
3. so it's cross-browser safe to use `forEach` on the result:

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]')].forEach((section) => {})
   ```
4. In that loop, simply add the classname to the `classList`:

   ```
   section.className.add('hidden')
   ```

Comment: If Nodelist.forEach not supported in the browser highly unlikely spread operator is

Comment: I guess because it's hard to read and because it has no explanation whatsoever

Comment: This solution just hides all elements by settings their class to "hidden". But the question also says, a single one should get a `unhidden` class.

Comment: @David this is just a snippet to hide all the selects, this isn't mean to be used to replace all of OP's code, just the part to achieve that.

Comment: @George where does it mention that?

Comment: @David in the question itself. _"How do I get JavaScript to change every tag with an ID that starts with "SubSub" to class="hidden"?"_

Comment: OP's question: *How do I get JavaScript to change every tag with an ID that starts with "SubSub" to class="hidden"?*

Comment: Guys, where does the _answer_ mention it is only meant to replace _parts_ of the code?

Comment: _then change the one I want to be visible to class='unhidden'._

Comment: @charlietfl `nodeList.forEach` is not transpiled by Babel, it's not even polyfilled by `@babel/polyfill`, so there is scenarios where using the spread operator works, but using NodeList.forEach() wouldn't work without additional hassle.

Comment: I rather doubt OP is transpiling with babel

Comment: @charlietfl They might not be, still noteworthy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getElementsByTagName` returns `HTMLCollection` which "not work" with for-in, instead use

```
for (let i =0; i<SubSub.length; i++) {
    let item = SubSub[i];
    if (item.id.match(/SubSub.*/)) {            
        item.className = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```js
function ShowSubSub(SelectID) {
    var SubSub = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
    console.log(SubSub);
    for (let i =0; i<SubSub.length; i++) {
        let item = SubSub[i];
        if (item.id.match(/SubSub.*/)) {            
            item.className = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    item = document.getElementById(SelectID);
    console.log(item);
    item.className = 'unhidden';
}

ShowSubSub('SubSubHome');
```

```css
.hidden {
  background: red;
}

.unhidden {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="SubSubFlood" >
    <option></option>
</select>
<select id="SubSubHome"  >
    <option></option>
</select>
```

I also develop a little improvement to [connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414897/860099) solution:

```
function ShowSubSub(SelectID) 
{
      [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]')].map(s => 
        s.id==SelectID ? s.className=('unhidden') : s.className=('hidden')
    )
}

ShowSubSub('SubSubHome');
```

```js
   function ShowSubSub(SelectID) 
{
   [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="SubSub"]')].map(s => 
     s.id==SelectID ? s.className=('unhidden') : s.className=('hidden')
    )
}

ShowSubSub('SubSubHome');
```

```css
.hidden {
  background: red;
}

.unhidden {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="SubSubFlood" >
    <option></option>
</select>
<select id="SubSubHome"  >
    <option></option>
</select>
```